# Is there recursive store procedures in MySql?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I want to know if is there recursive procedures in MySql and how can I implement them

Comment: What is it you want them for?

Comment: You'll get more helpful answers if you are more specific (information, data sample and expected result) about what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

By default, recursion is disabled because it does affect things like required thread stack space in the server and so on. You can allow recursion by setting the [max_sp_recursion_depth](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sp_recursion_depth) server variable, but I would *highly* discourage it.